# Intellij don't see my jdk-11 enviornment FEDORA 29

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've got problem with my Intellij idea community edition.
I'm working on Fedora 29.

Java, jdk, jre, everythin' is installed properly.

I'd like to change sdk, i don't see path /usr/lib/jvm/

Link to screen, how problem look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGVG8.jpg

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA version do you use? You need to specify the JAVA_HOME location, not the path where java binary symlink is.

Comment: Please make better screenshots.

Comment: @JoshAdams The linked question is incorrectly answered.

Comment: What location do you specify as JAVA_HOME in IntelliJ IDEA when selecting the JDK installation directory?

Comment: @CrazyCoder     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk

Comment: @Eloix what's the output from `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/bin/java -version` command?

Comment: but this path isn't exists in Intellij IDEA.                          https://imgur.com/a/9Vz0JJ3

Comment: @Eloix you may need to install it per https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-11-lts-on-centos/ and configure the correct location for JAVA_HOME that exists and works on your system.

Comment: @CrazyCoder  I did everything what was in this site but after restart I can't log to my computer. Credentials are good cuz for 1 second I've got black screen and then back to logging panel. I tried to do something via ctrl+alt+F2, but I can't do anything. Sudo, su, RM, cat and almost others command don't work. What should I do now?

Comment: @Eloix I have no idea how installing a JDK can cause such a problem. You may want to perform some system recovery.

Comment: @CrazyCoder as I said

Comment: @CrazyCoder as I said. I can't do anything. I've got only a few commands to use. I don't want to reinstall the system.

Comment: @Eloix Sorry, I can't help with this system level issue. You may want to report a separate question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/ and describe your problem with more details.